# Why does WebSQL not work with iOS applications made with PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I just ported my PhoneGap application into the iOS platform, it would seem that the iPad I'm testing on (as well as the simulators provided by xCode) do not want to work properly with WebSQL...

I've chased the issue down to the root, I think. Essentially when I try to open/create the database the app just hangs and doesn't continue past this point...

Here's my clip of my code...

```
var SQLAPI = function()
{
    self.Init = function()
    {
        // DB Name, Verion Number, Text Description, Estimated Size of DB
        var size = 1000 * 1024 * 1024;
        if(IsMobile())
        {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function()
            {
                alert("Started Device Ready");
                self.db = window.openDatabase("MyDB", "1.0", "My Database", size);
                alert("Started Made DB");
                alert("Started DB");
            }, false);
        }
        else
        {
            self.db = window.openDatabase("MyDB", "1.0", "My Database", size);
            alert("started DB 2")
        }
    };
};
```

The problem arises at the following code...

```
alert("Started Device Ready");
self.db = window.openDatabase("MyDB", "1.0", "My Database", size);
alert("Started Made DB");
alert("Started DB");
```

The first alert saying "Started Device Ready" is fired, so an alert box appears saying that text.

It then tries to run window.openDatabase and something happens at this point because it will not execute the next set of alerts ever....

The app works on Browsers, Android devices, etc... It's just on iOS that this issue happens.

Comment: [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) is an abandoned standard and support for it may have been removed. If the execution stops at that line, there should be an error. Wrap it in a `try..catch` and inspect the error that's being thrown.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yes, but iOS is one of the few that did/does support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not working on iOS because you're requesting a database size which far exceeds the allowed limit: 1000 * 1024 * 1024 == 1Gb

The established upper limit for a WebSQL DB in an iOS WebView is 50Mb ([see here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)].

It may work on other platforms either because they allow unlimited size or if requested size is greater than the limit, they cap it to that limit.

Try reducing the size of the DB to below 50Mb e.g. 49*1024*1024

If you need a database with larger capacity than this, consider using something like [this native SQLite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) as a drop-in replacement for WebSQL with unlimited storage capacity.

Comment: Making the change from WebSQL to a Native SQLite plugin is not feasible for me at this time... Although it is something that I would love to do in the future given the right plugin....

Does this plugin work for both Android and iOS, I saw that there was a build failed notification for the iOS on the GitHub page.

Comment: The SQLite plugin is definitely working on iOS, despite the build failed notification. I use it in conjunction with [another plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter) that I wrote - you can see for yourself that the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example-native-plugin) builds and runs fine on iOS

Comment: As for the feasibility of swapping out WebSQL for native SQLite, the change is a one-liner when using this plugin since it's intended as a drop-in replacement for WebSQL - simply replace `window.openDatabase()` with `sqlitePlugin.openDatabase()` and the interface is exactly the same on the returned object.

Comment: Oh wow really, that is impressive. I'll definitely take a look into this. Thanks!